# Substring in XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need help with one scenario: I need to substring before the last occurrence of space, hyphen or full stop characters in a text. I tried with substring-before

For example, If text is 'SIR WILLIAM SIEMENS SQUARE', then I need to have 'SIR WILLIAM SIEMENS' as first text string and 'SQUARE'. Using Substring before I am getting 'SIR' and 'WILLIAM SIEMENS SQUARE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to replace (. and -) with space and then it will work. Try like this.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:variable name="maintext" select="replace(replace(/root/a, '\.', '. '), '-', '- ')"/>
        <a><xsl:value-of select="tokenize($maintext, ' ')[position() != last()]"/></a>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="tokenize($maintext, ' ')[last()]"/></b>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <a><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ' ')[position() != last()]"/></a>
    <b><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ' ')[last()]"/></b>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks, but in my scenario, I need to substring before last occurrence of space, or hypen or full stop. For example, if text is 'SIR WILLIAM SIEME N.SSQUARE' then need to substring as 'SIR WILLIAM SIEME N.' and 'SSQUARE'

Answer (score 0):

you can also use analyze-string

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(.)" regex="(.+[\W])([\w]+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <a><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(1))"/></a>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></b>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```